# Is there a term for the type of communication where the feedback is immediate, as opposed to delayed?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I often try to distinguish between immediate-feedback communication, such as talking in person, on the phone, or by instant message, and delayed-feedback communication, such as email.  (Or at least, delayed in the sense that it's socially acceptable to not respond right away.)

I usually would say something like, "I'd prefer to discuss this in real-time," which usually gets the point across, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to describe this concept.  ("Can we talk about this using an immediate-feedback medium?" sounds a little awkward.)

Comment: I think *real-time* is the word I'd reach for the most in this situation. *Face-to-face* is a related concept with additional physical presence. *Directly* might also be a word that could apply in this case.

Comment: One of the hallmarks of electronic textual communication is the ability to think before responding. One of the hallmarks of electronic textual communication is the frequency of not-thinking before responding. The concept of *real-time* communication, both face-to-face and telephonic (but not voice mail) is the lack of time to reflect, but the advantage of immediacy and transparency. *Real-time* sounds fine. Also *live* might work.

Answer (score 4):

In pedagogical terms, we talk about "synchronous" vs. "asyncronous" communication.

In synchronous communication, we're talking to each other at the same time; in asynchronous communication, you may not see what I'm saying as I'm saying it, and you may reply at a later time.

Comment: Hi, Sean, and welcome to English Language & Usage. This is a very promising answer, so I'm upvoting it—but I think it would be even stronger if you added a link to or citation of a reference authority that confirms your description of synchronous and asynchronous communication.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. In some ways, you are suggesting "active feedback" rather than passive, though that is not a common term and it doesn't mean "asap".

Tech companies I have worked for also discuss a "positive handoff" which means reaching out to the person actively, such as via phone (I just emailed you the report) or in person (Here is the report) as opposed to a passive medium like email or a phone message. This is used for accountability purposes (I had a positive handoff of the contract with client X on 1/1/11, so he can't say he didn't know it was finished...)

Comment: +1 for "positive handoff". Not sure of origin.

Comment: ...so I've opened https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548648/etymology-for-positive-handoff