# Etymology for "positive handoff" or "positive hand-off"

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology/origin of the phrase "positive handoff" (or "hand-off", meaning an explicit transfer of something (objects or currency or information or responsibility) between two parties that both are actively engaged in, so that the sender can be sure that the receiver gets the thing and is aware of receiving it.

As an example, the actions of a [process server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_of_process) would constitute a positive handoff.

Usage examples:

> For freight rail, the rule will ensure the positive handoff of security-sensitive materials as well as establish security protocols for custody transfers of security-sensitive material rail cars.
>
> (https://www.joc.com/regulation-policy/dhs-releases-rail-security-final-rule_20081112.html)

> Finally, I expect a positive handoff to test.  By this I mean a detailed TRD (test release document) that describes what the feature does, what works, what doesn’t work, and suggestions for testing the feature.
>
> https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2007/07/23/what-makes-a-good-software-developer/

> Have your child use a bathroom in the gate area at some point before boarding.  If traveling under unaccompanied-minor procedures, he or she will be escorted onto the airplane during pre-boarding.  Airline policies call for a positive hand-off of your child from one employee to the next.  At the destination, the person meeting your child may have to show ID (many airlines require photo ID).  Even a parent may have to show ID when picking up the child at the end of the trip.
>
> http://avstop.com/news_july_2010/when_kids_fly_alone.htm

> Throughout the exercise series, the participants have developed tactics, techniques and procedures to effectively notify, coordinate, and conduct positive handoff of a hijacked aircraft flying through Russian, Canadian and American airspace, Viens told reporters during a teleconference today.
>
> https://archive.defense.gov/news/newsarticle.aspx?id=120694

> When aircraft cross into a new ATC Control Sector, they are handed off to a new controller on a separate frequency. In some places, this process is entirely automated. But when an emergency is in progress, these automated processes largely disappear. Controllers use a landline connection to speak with the next controller before handing off the emergency aircraft to them. This is an important step in guaranteeing a positive handoff between controllers. It's also a way for controllers to brief each other on the specifics of the situation which they might not be aware of.
>
> https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/what-happens-when-you-declare-an-emergency-with-atc/

> A simple technique from aviation, the “positive handoff,” can be beneficial, even life-saving. Here’s how it works. When a plane moves from one airspace to the next, air traffic control provides the pilot with the new communication frequency. The pilot confirms the frequency, then checks in with the next set of controllers. ATC and the pilot all know and agree on who is responsible for communication as the flight is handed off from one zone to the next.
>
> Similarly, if there are two or more pilots on a flight, it’s essential to know who is in charge. A pilot who needs to consult a chart or check the weather may say to his or her partner, “Your airplane.” “My airplane” is the confirmation. There is no ambiguity about who is flying the airplane.
>
> Parents can adopt this practice poolside to securely transfer supervision from one adult to another. When it is “your baby,” acknowledge that out loud and take the responsibility seriously. No looking at your phone, no “just running inside for a second,” no goofing around with friends, no doing anything that distracts you from your supervisory obligation. Take turns with other adults so you have time to enjoy the party, too. When your shift is over, the positive handoff makes it clear who is now in charge of a baby or toddler. That eliminates the possibly tragic confusion of the “I thought you were watching him!” “No, I thought YOU were watching him!” scenario.
>
> https://www.safebeesideme.com/blogs/news/don-t-let-a-pool-party-turn-into-a-tragedy

Is it from military use? football? first responders / hospital ER? Air traffic control? (as three of the examples might suggest)

Comment: “The relay method of racing was started in the United States about 1883. ... In sprint relays (400 and 800 metres) a 1964 rule change permitted the runner receiving the baton to start his run 10 metres or 11 yards before the zone, but he had to take the baton within the zone itself.”
Britannica.com › ... › Olympic Sports
Relay race | race format | Britannica

Comment: So, probably relay races where the runner hands off the baton to the next runner. Probably there’s something earlier.

Comment: but did they use the term "positive handoff"?

Comment: "Handoff" (or "hand-off") has been around a long time.  Possibly related to the "hand-off" in relay races (which probably go back 2000 years or more), though the term "hand off" meaning to pass to someone else does not require a specific origin.

Comment: “Positive handoff” and “negative handoff” do not appear in Google NGrams, although I think the meaning can be inferred from the texts you quote.

Comment: sigh. not sure why the -1. This is a term I have heard used in engineering companies and I would like to know where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any definitive origin, but the earliest mentions I can find were in Senate hearings in 1961:

From [*Hearings Before the Aviation Subcomittee of the Committee on Interstate and Foreign Commerce, United States Senate, Eighty-seventh Congress, First Session on Air Safety*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SElJAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA550&dq=%22handoff%22) (Feb 20 - Mar 8, 1961):

> Senator MONRONEY. I am not so concerned with that. I am concerned with United approaching Preston and this handoff at that point, whether, if there is known instrumentation in the bright display, where this target could have been carried in and observed going beyond Preston by an area man, or at the point if he had not already passed Preston have been turned over and given a positive radar handoff to the control tower at Idlewild?
>
> Mr THOMAS. Electronic means there is not today, and this is an electronic contract Mr. Anast was speaking of that we hope to have in 12 months.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. In 12 months?
>
> Mr THOMAS. Yes, sir.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. The old system that was developed at the CAA center would not be adaptable?
>
> As I understand, that was an electric pencil?
>
> Mr THOMAS. Yes, sir.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. I thought there was a new one which they had devised, a sort of a joystick application, with which you could follow internally the progress of the plane as the control tower man brought it along, keeping it circled and in the scope.
>
> The question was, to my mind, could that be wired into the approach control from the area control?
>
> Mr. THOMAS. This is the development that is underway at present time essentially. We have the problem of registration between two radars looking at airplanes from different perspectives and therefore giving different locations, too.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. This is on the same airport I am talking about.
>
> Mr. THOMAS. But they are separate radars.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. But they are not too far separate. In other words, it seems to me like it would even pay, if a positive radar handoff is required, to have this on the scope even in the control tower so that the air traffic controller bringing it in would be able to pick him up positively on his approach radar then from reference to perhaps the long-range radar that is piped in. Maybe it is a captive or slave television set working there, but some way to perfect a positive handoff.
>
> Mr. THOMAS. Sir, we want this desperately.

and from [*Hearings Before the Subcomittee of the Committee on Appropriations, United States Senate, Eighty-seventh Congress, First Session on H.R. 7446 Making Appropriations for Sundry Independent Executive Bureaus, Boards, Commissions, Corporations, Agencies, and Offices, for the Fiscal Year ending June 30 1962, and for Other Purposes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SElJAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA550&dq=%22handoff%22), June 1961 (specifically the transcript of Tuesday, June 20, 1961)

> Mr. HALABY. There are two principal experiments, Senator, which derive from work within the Agency and the disclosures in the unfilled mint of ideas developed during your hearings on safety last winter.
>
> One is technique for passing and airplane which is on one radarscope in one sector of the airspace over to another, and to assure that there is a continuous control in the process of flow of that aircraft.
>
> Senator MONRONEY. Positive radar handoff.
>
> Mr. HALABY. Positive radar handoff, as it is called. What that means is to provide additional personel to enable one radar position, one radar control, to positively identify a particular radar target to another, and insure the handing off of radar control to the second position before ending his own surveillance.